# Is it possible in the BIOS to set a physical cpu (assuming i have more than one) to be ignored so nothing gets scheduled on it unless i taskset to it?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, bios

If so I'd be curious as to how. I heard this was a possible way of isolating a cpu to have for yourself. (With nothing else being scheduled to run there unless you do it yourself). This would seem to be ideal for performance testing on a machine or for experimenting with a cpu uninhibited by other processes. (Linux OS by the way)

Comment: Only if your BIOS supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you could dedicate a cpu from bios. operating systems usually override almost everything bioses do. Better to do it from the OS

Comment: schedutils , sched_setaffinity is probably what you want

Comment: and maybe kernel option isolcpus

Comment: Well sched_setaffinity wouldn't prevent some RT daemons i often see running at priority 139 from possibly interfering..it wouldn't quite give me cpu isolation? isolcpus i haven't heard of but it looks like a stronger guarantee than sched_setaffinity

Comment: yeah but isolcpus should prevent that

Comment: Quick followup though..will isolcplus isolate a physical cpu or can it be used to isolate a logical one (like a core)?